# How can debug in Flash Develop?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flashdevelop

I recently installed Flash Develop and made a new project in AS3.

When you press F5 receive this error:

```
The project doesn`t have a valid SDK defined.Please check the SDK tab in the Project Properties
```

How to install this SDK?

He happened to someone this problem?

You show me a tutorial how can I solve this problem?
Develop Flash SDK does not come installed with?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, you need to download Flex SDK. IIRC FlashDevelop prompts you to download the SDK at installation. Also you will need latest Flash debug standalone player, download that separately.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not find a tutorial to show me step by step how to do it ... because I tried installation and I do not work.Can you show me a link with a tutorial please?

Comment: Usually FlashDevelop install goes "next - next - finished". I see, howeber, that you have succeed in launching a sample AS3 Flash program, so maybe you've succeeded already.

Answer (score 0):

You may not have installed an SDK when you installed the program. When you install Flash Develop a menu should appear that allows you to install all the pieces it needs in order to run (including an SDK). My best bet would be to simply uninstall Flash Develop and reinstall and see if the window pops up to let you install an SDK.

If you don't want to uninstall Flash Develop, then when you open Flash Develop, click "Project" on the top of the window and then click "Properties" on the drop down menu. Click the "SDK" tab and see if you have an SDK in the "Installed SDK(s)" window. I, for instance, have "Default (Flex 4.6.0, AIR 17.0)" in my "Installed SDK(s)" window. If it's not showing an SDK, then you have to download and install one and apply it on the "SDK" tab.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Flash Develop installation folder
2. Open Tools/Appman/Appman.exe
3. From the list select "Flex SDK" and "Flash Player (SA)" and maybe
   some themes and other extra things...
4. Click Install items and you are done.